# Check if user computer's window is idle (Java)?

Tags: java, desktop

I want to create a notifications application for desktops which would show notifications/popups only when user is idle. By idle I mean when user can see his/hers desktop wallpaper and no program is blocking a single pixel of the desktop - http://prntscr.com/feorvd.

If someone knows how to better express what I want you are welcome to do edit the topic.

**EDIT:** I don't want for a popup to show up in the middle of a movie or a game ect. I don't want to be forced to shoo it away because it is blocking content that I want to give all my attention to.

Comment: Why would you want to use Java for this when it was developed with a main purpose to be as far removed from the OS as possible? Also your question is a bit over-broad. Please use the results of your own research to try to make it more specific.

Comment: Why does "seeing the desktop" equate to idle?  It might be idle even if the desktop cannot be seen, or it might be running services in the background if the desktop can be seen.  Why not try and check the CPU usage instead?

Comment: @SteveSmith couldn't background services still mean the user is idle? In that case the CPU usage might not be a good indicator - input devices (keyboard, mouse) not sending events might be a better option (although the user might still not be "idle", e.g. when reading a lengthy text ;) ).

Comment: @Thomas I was probably wrong in assuming that "user is idle" actually meant the computer is idle.  If OP genuinely means the user, then you're probably right.  and presumably the popup will say "Do some work!". :)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Well I am a Java person and want to develop something for myself. And seems you are implying that Java is OS dependant, which is opposite what they say about Java

Comment: @JuliuxD: Please re-read my comment. I stated that it was developed to be removed form the OS, meaning that it strives to be OS ***agnostic***. You will want to use something a little closer to the metal such as C# if a Windows project.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, got your point.